# How to check if a cell is empty if it contains a reference value?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to check a cell of a dropdown list if empty using `IFBLANK` or `IF(A4="","blank","not blank"` but always returns false.. How can I overcome this to see if any value chosen or just empty string?

Comment: *"I want to check a cell of a dropdown list if empty..."* There is no such function as `IFBLANK`. However. Both `IF` and `ISBLANK` return [correct results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TkjW.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `countblank()` to solve the problem to return either zero or 1.

Comment: Returning `0` or `1` is not what you asked for in your post. Even so, using `IF` [still works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLRZ0.png)

Comment: Thanks. Yes ISBLANK what I mean in the question. The problem is that the cell that has a reference value like List of range, It returns FALSE weather it is empty or has a value. So making a conditional formatting based on that is not possible. If I have 0 or 1 then I can do conditional formatting.